# Changing Active Directory user password from java program

Tags: java, active-directory, passwords, ldap

I have Active Directory, with Users in it, i am trying to change a users password from a Java Program as follows:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"user1");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"pass1");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ADSecurityProtocol");
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://host:389/OU=My Org,DC=domain,DC=com");
try
{
     LdapContext ctx =new InitialLdapContext(prop,null);
     String oldPassword="pass1";
     String newPassword="passnew1";
     ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[2];
     String oldQuotedPassword = "\"" + oldPassword + "\"";
     byte[] oldUnicodePassword = oldQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
     String newQuotedPassword = "\"" + newPassword + "\"";
     byte[] newUnicodePassword = newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

     mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE,
                   new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", oldUnicodePassword));
     mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE,
                   new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newUnicodePassword));

     String theUserName="CN="+"user1"+",OU=My Org,DC=domain,DC=com";
     // Perform the update
     ctx.modifyAttributes(theUserName, mods);
     System.out.println("Changed Password for successfully");
     ctx.close();
}
     catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("Problem changing password: " + e);
}
```

The error message i get is:

```
Problem changing password: javax.naming.NamingException: 
[LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007DB, 
problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0]; remaining name 
'CN=user1,OU=My Org,DC=domain,DC=com'
```

**Edit 1:**

**Based on Suggestions i have tried this with port 636 and ldaps as well:**

```
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://host:636/OU=My Org,DC=domain,DC=com");  
Also tried
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://host:636/OU=My Org,DC=domain,DC=com");  

I am getting MalformedURLException: Invalid URI: 
Invalid URI: Org,DC=domain,DC=com]
```

When i try (not sure if anything is listening on 636, it appears it is tho):

```
$ telnet LDAPHost 636
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**Edit2:**

```
Changed:
 prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://host:636/OU=My Org,DC=domain,DC=com");  
to:
 prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://host:636/OU=My%20Org,DC=domain,DC=com");
```

The error is:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: host:636 
[Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]
```

Probably the LDAP Server is not even listening on ssl port: 636

Comment: do you have solved this question?

Answer (score 6):

> [The `unicodePwd`] attribute can be written under restricted conditions [...] In order to modify this attribute, the client must have a 128-bit Secure Socket Layer (SSL) connection to the server.

You only have a plain unsecure `ldap://` connection instead of `ldaps://`, so that won't work according to the above restrictions.

See more details at:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269190

Comment: Tried it, see additional details in question. I get a different error: MalformedURLException: Invalid URI: Org,DC=domain,DC=com].

Comment: I think using an SSL secured connection will require some more work beyond changing the url. See some resources [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/misc/url.html), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ssl.html#CLIENT), and [here](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/UsingLDAPSWithJNDI).

Comment: Also, have you tried replacing the space char with "%20" in the url?

Comment: zagyi> After i replaced My Org part of the URL with My%20Org, i get: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: host:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset], ...... It appears our LDAP Server is not enabled to run in ssl mode?

Answer (score 2):

The JVM executing the password change call needs to be trusted by the directory service provider. This means importing a certificate generated from AD into the JVM trust store.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, then you can call [`NetUserChangePassword()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserchangepassword) function that is available inside `netapi32.dll`.

Using [`JNA`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna), the code will be like this:

```
public static int changeActiveDirectoryUserPassword(String activeDirectoryIP, String username, String oldPassword, String newPassword)
{
    int status = Netapi32.INSTANCE.NetUserChangePassword(activeDirectoryIP, username, oldPassword, newPassword);

    switch(status)
    {
        case WinError.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER: // The parameter is incorrect
        case WinError.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED: // The user does not have access to the requested information
        case WinError.ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD: // The user has entered an invalid password
        case LMErr.NERR_InvalidComputer: // The computer name is invalid
        case LMErr.NERR_NotPrimary: // The operation is allowed only on the primary domain controller of the domain
        case LMErr.NERR_UserNotFound: // The user name could not be found
        case LMErr.NERR_PasswordTooShort: // The password is shorter than required. (The password could also be too
                                          // long, be too recent in its change history, not have enough unique
                                          // characters, or not meet another password policy requirement.)
        case LMErr.NERR_Success: // function succeeds
        default: return status;
    }
}
```

---

<strike>**Note:** Unlike the ldap approach, this approach will work even if the old password is already expired.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to modify the `unicodePwd` attribute of the user.

I use AWS Simple AD implementation and, as it is based on Samba 4, this attribute doesn't work. You need to use `clearTextPassword` in this case. See my blog post about it:
http://blog.techutils.space/2016/02/changing-samba4-aws-simple-ad-user.html

Note: AWS Simple AD doesn't support SSL yet, so find a way to mitigate this risk.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the attribute. Try to change `unicodePwd` with`userpassword`

from :

```
 mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE,
               new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", oldUnicodePassword));
 mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE,
               new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newUnicodePassword));
```

to :

```
mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE,
                   new BasicAttribute("userpassword", oldUnicodePassword));
mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE,
                   new BasicAttribute("userpassword", newUnicodePassword));
```