# Change Active Directory password using Kerberos Change-Password protocol and .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, active-directory, kerberos

It is possible to change password of AD user using LDAP protocol. However, if the user has to change his password at next logon (or the password is expired), then the password cannot be changed unless by using admin credentials. I was able to solve this issue [in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51511518/597657) by using WIN32 API. Unfortunately, I cannot use WINAPI in linux environment.

As per [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/264480/description-of-password-change-protocols-in-windows):

> When a user changes his or her own password by pressing CTRL+ALT+DELETE and then clicking Change Password, Windows NT up to Windows 2003 the NetUserChangePassword mechanism (method 1) is used if the target is a domain. **From Windows Vista onwards, the Kerberos change password protocol is used for domain accounts**. If the target is a Kerberos realm, the Kerberos change-password protocol (method 3) is used.

I looked for Kerberos client that can run on .NET Core and I found [`SteveSyfuhs/Kerberos.NET`](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/Kerberos.NET).

By reading [Kerberos Change Password Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-cat-kerb-chg-password-02) and [Kerberos.NET Samples](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/Kerberos.NET/tree/master/Samples), I wrote the following code:

```
using Kerberos.NET;
using Kerberos.NET.Client;
using Kerberos.NET.Credentials;
using Kerberos.NET.Crypto;
using Kerberos.NET.Entities;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KerberosDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string activeDirectoryServer = "10.12.34.56:88"; // kdc port
            string domain = "TEST.LOCAL";
            string username = "testuser@" + domain;
            string oldPassword = "123";
            string newPassword = "456";

            using var client = new KerberosClient(activeDirectoryServer);
            var kerbCred = new KerberosPasswordCredential(username, oldPassword, domain);
            await client.Authenticate(kerbCred);
            var serviceTicket = await client.GetServiceTicket("kadmin/changepw");

            var apReq = new KrbApReq
            {
                Ticket = serviceTicket.Ticket,
                Authenticator = KrbEncryptedData.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newPassword).AsMemory(), kerbCred.CreateKey(), KeyUsage.ApReqAuthenticator),
                ProtocolVersionNumber = 1
            };

            var tcp = client.Transports.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Protocol == ProtocolType.Tcp);
            await tcp.SendMessage<KrbApReq, KrbAsRep>(domain, apReq);
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following exception at `await tcp.SendMessage<KrbApReq, KrbAsRep>(domain, apReq);`:

> Unhandled exception.
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: ASN1 corrupted
> data.    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.Asn1.AsnReader.ReadTagAndLength(Nullable`1& contentsLength, Int32& bytesRead) in d:\a\1\s\Kerberos.NET\Asn1\Experimental\AsnReader.cs:line 305    at Kerberos.NET.Entities.KrbError.CanDecode(ReadOnlyMemory`1 encoded) in
> d:\a\1\s\Kerberos.NET\Entities\Krb\KrbError.cs:line 23    at
> Kerberos.NET.Transport.KerberosTransportBase.Decode[T](ReadOnlyMemory`1 response) in d:\a\1\s\Kerberos.NET\Client\Transport\KerberosTransportBase.cs:line 41    at Kerberos.NET.Transport.TcpKerberosTransport.ReadResponse[T](NetworkStream stream, CancellationToken cancellation) in d:\a\1\s\Kerberos.NET\Client\Transport\TcpKerberosTransport.cs:line 69 at Kerberos.NET.Transport.TcpKerberosTransport.SendMessage[T](String domain, ReadOnlyMemory`1 encoded, CancellationToken cancellation) in
> d:\a\1\s\Kerberos.NET\Client\Transport\TcpKerberosTransport.cs:line 58
> at KerberosDemo.Program.Main(String[] args)    at
> KerberosDemo.Program.(String[] args)

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *"if the user has to change his password at next logon (or the password is expired), then the password cannot be changed unless by using admin credentials"* - Are you sure about this? If you are trying to authenticate to LDAP using the user's own credentials, then I can see it being a problem. But as long as you can authenticate to LDAP using *any* credentials, then you should be able to change the user's password by providing the old password.

Comment: @Gabriel If the user's password is not valid (for the 2 reasons I mentioned), it cannot be used to authenticate against LDAP server (AD). Also, I have no admin credentials to use instead.

Comment: Right. So an alternative is to not use the user's credentials to authenticate. You can authenticate with any account (use a service account for example, but it doesn't need any special permissions - *any* domain account will do) then you can change the password as you normally would. Sending the old password during the change password operation is the only authorization you need to change the password.

Comment: You are right. It turns out that I just need to use secure protocol LDAPS (port 636) in order to change password. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! That too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may as well write this into an answer.

> if the user has to change his password at next logon (or the password is expired), then the password cannot be changed unless by using admin credentials

This can be a problem if you're using the user's own credentials to authenticate to AD, which is a common way to verify a user's credentials. If the user's password is expired (or specifically set to force change on next logon) then the authentication will fail and you are prevented from looking up the user's account and changing the password.

To get around that, you can use a different account to authenticate to AD. *It does not have to be an admin account*. Any domain credentials will do. Then you can lookup the user's account.

Since you must know the old password to change the password, AD considers *that* all the authorization you need to change it.

That is different than *resetting* the password, where you need an account that has "Reset password" permission on the account.

And as you found out, you also need to be connected to AD securely, so that the new password is not sent in plain text.

All of this is documented in the [documentation for the `unicodePwd` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2).