# How to reset an LDAP password in Spring (Forgotten password)

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

In a Spring Boot `1.5.9` application, I have a reset my password. Using a token, I am able to identify the user that is resetting he's password.

This is how I update a password of a connected user:

```java
public void updatePassword(User entity) {
  if (null != entity.getOldPassword() && null != entity.getPassword()) {
    userDetailsService.changePassword(entity.getOldPassword(), encrypt(entity.getPassword()));
  }
}
```

I use `LdapUserDetailsManager userDetailsService`, from spring security ldap `4.2.3.RELEASE`, I do not see any method to reset the password of an user I have the `username` from.

How can I reset a password using the `username` (or `uid` in ldap)?

Comment: Thats because LDAP is primary for obtaining credentials, to change them you typically need to use additional API, specific for each vendor. As example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335614/changing-active-directory-user-password-from-java-program

Comment: I already went trought that example but that is not for ldap, this is for active directory. I have not found yet a solution to update an existing password and this example is not helping me.

Comment: LDAP is  specification, Microsoft Active Directory is one of implementations. Which LDAP server do you use?

Comment: Open LDAP. I have read this: https://tech.wrighting.org/2013/06/06/using-the-ldap-password-modify-extended-operation-with-spring-ldap/ and I am trying it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in this post: https://tech.wrighting.org/2013/06/06/using-the-ldap-password-modify-extended-operation-with-spring-ldap/

This is how I did:

```java
    DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName(dn_string);
    Attribute passwordAttribute = new BasicAttribute(passwordAttr,
            newPassword);
    ModificationItem[] modificationItems = new ModificationItem[1];
    modificationItems[0] = new ModificationItem(
            DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, passwordAttribute);
/*
    Attribute userPasswordChangedAttribute = new BasicAttribute(
            LDAP_PASSWORD_CHANGE_DATE, format.format(convertToUtc(null)
                    .getTime()) + "Z");
    ModificationItem newPasswordChanged = new ModificationItem(
            DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, userPasswordChangedAttribute);
    modificationItems[1] = newPasswordChanged;
    */
    getLdapTemplate().modifyAttributes(dn, modificationItems);
```

I prefered this method since the version I am using of spring security ldap is not using the password overlay to change the password, for more consistency with it, otherwise, if you are using a more recent version of spring security ldap, prefer the second way of doing it.